# Polynomial of Linear Operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $L$ denote a linear operator and $v\in V$. Does the expression $$c_0L^nv + c_1L^{n-1}v + \cdots + c_{n-1}L^1v + c_nL^0v = 0$$
has a special name and what properties are known? For example, I know that if $n$ is the smallest natural number such that $L^nv = 0$, then $c_i = 0$ for all $i$. Or, if $n = 1$ we know many things because the equation becomes $c_0Lv + c_1v = 0$ which is related to eigenvalues/vectors. Powers of $L$ also appear in Krylov spaces.

So this equation seems interesting and I would be inerested to read more about it.

Answer (score 2):

It's one easy way to generalize operator-valued functions $f(A)$ if $f(x)$ is a polynomial and $A$ is an operator. What you have written is the kernel of $f(A)$ as an operator.

---

EDITED: As for properties of $f(A)$, well, there's a whole theory devoted to understanding properties of $f(A)$. Could be overkill, but Operator theory could help. For finite dimensions, you could probably look at Topics in matrix analysis by Horn and Johnson.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that $W$ should be the same vector space as $V$ if we want to form powers of $L$.

As @chhro wrote, what you have written is the statement that $v$ lies in the kernel of the operator $f(L)$.  I would like to add the clarification that if you meant $f(L)$ to be identically zero (i.e., $f(L)v$ to be zero for *all* $v$ in $V$), then the concept you probably want is that of the [*minimal polynomial*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)), and the linked article lists a key result on this topic: the Hamilton-Cayley theorem.